# Migrating from AngularDart 0.14.0 to 1.0.0

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I have a fairly large web application that is build using the @Controller annotation in AngularDart 0.14.0. The @Controller annotation has been removed so I need to migrate to something else. So my questions are what do I migrate to, and how do I do it. I have looked at the documentation for the @Component annotation, but I don’t see a way to migrate to it without requiring a large amount of rework. I hope that I am missing something. I have looked at other similar questions, but none of them have lead me to a solution.

Here is a cut down example of how I am using @Controller.

**pubspec.yaml**

```yaml
name: Admin
description: Server Admin Page
dependencies:
  angular: 0.14.0
transformers:
- angular:
    html_files: web/index.html
```

**index.html**

```dart
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" >
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Server Configuration</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div admin id="container">
    <div id="header">
      <div id="app-header"><span id="app-name">Server Configuration</span></div>
      <div class="tab-panel ng-cloak" >
        <div class="{{ctrl.selectedTab != null && tab.name == ctrl.selectedTab.name ? 'tab-selected' : 'tab'}}" ng-repeat="tab in ctrl.tabs">
          <div class='tab-inner' ng-click='ctrl.selectTab(tab)'>{{tab.name}}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="body">
    <div class="ng-cloak" ng-if="ctrl.selectedTab != null" >
      <div>{{ctrl.selectedTab.name}} Content</div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="application/dart" src="index.dart"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**index.dart**

```dart
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
import 'package:angular/application_factory.dart';

@Controller(
    selector: '[admin]',
    publishAs: 'ctrl')
class AdminPage{
  AbstractTab selectedTab;
  List<AbstractTab> tabs = new List<AbstractTab>();

  AdminPage()
  {   
    tabs.add(new AbstractTab("tab1","tab"));
    tabs.add(new AbstractTab("tab2","tab"));

    this.selectTab(tabs.first);
  }

  void selectTab(AbstractTab tab)
  {
    this.selectedTab = tab;
    this.selectedTab.load();
  } 
}

class AbstractTab{
  String name;
  String type;

  AbstractTab(this.name,this.type);

  load()
  {
    print("loading $name");
  }
}

class MyAppModule extends Module {
  MyAppModule() {
    bind(AdminPage);
  }
}

void main() {
  applicationFactory()
      .addModule(new MyAppModule())
      .run();
}
```

**Update:**

My updated index.dart file now looks like this, and everything is working in AngularDart 1.0.0. Thank you for the assistance.

```dart
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
import 'package:angular/application_factory.dart';

class AdminPage{
  AbstractTab selectedTab;
  List<AbstractTab> tabs = new List<AbstractTab>();

  AdminPage()
  {   
    tabs.add(new AbstractTab("tab1","tab"));
    tabs.add(new AbstractTab("tab2","tab"));

    this.selectTab(tabs.first);
  }

  void selectTab(AbstractTab tab)
  {
    this.selectedTab = tab;
    this.selectedTab.load();
  } 
}

class AbstractTab{
  String name;
  String type;

  AbstractTab(this.name,this.type);

  load()
  {
    print("loading $name");
  }
}

@Injectable() // don't forget that
class GlobalController {
  AdminPage ctrl;

  GlobalController() {
    ctrl = new AdminPage();
  }
}

void main() {
  applicationFactory().rootContextType(GlobalController).run();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been in the same situation like you, and I have to admit that documentation about "how to do it properly in angular V1" is lacking.

So actually, the best way I found is to use a global controller

***main.dart***

```dart
@Injectable() // don't forget that
class GlobalController {
  final Logger log = new Logger("GlobalController");
  AdminPage ctrl;
  OtherCtrl otherCtrl

  GlobalController() {
    ctrl = new AdminPage();
    otherCtrl = new OtherCtrl();
  }
}

void main() {
  applicationFactory().rootContextType(GlobalController).run();
}
```

***index.html***

```dart
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" >
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Server Configuration</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div admin id="container">
    <div id="header">
      <div id="app-header"><span id="app-name">Server Configuration</span></div>
      <div class="tab-panel ng-cloak" >
        <div class="{{ctrl.selectedTab != null && tab.name == ctrl.selectedTab.name ? 'tab-selected' : 'tab'}}" ng-repeat="tab in ctrl.tabs">
          <div class='tab-inner' ng-click='ctrl.selectTab(tab)'>{{tab.name}}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="body">
    <div class="ng-cloak" ng-if="ctrl.selectedTab != null" >
      <div>{{ctrl.selectedTab.name}} Content</div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="application/dart" src="index.dart"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

It works perfectly for me.

**Note:** Notice that all method and field of your `GlobalController` will be directly accessible. in this example if you want to access to `otherCtrl`, just use `otherCtrl` in your HTML file.

**Note2:** You don't have to put anything in your HTML balise to make this work.

***Information:*** I know in migration you can't allow big refactoring, but for you future development, Angular advice to split your code into more components.

[rootContextType](https://docs.angulardart.org/#angular/angular-app-factory-static)